# udev not generating /dev/disk directory in yocto linux build

Tags: systemd, udev, disk, block-device, yocto

I have built a yocto linux image for a SAMA5 board. After I booted, udev did not generate the `/dev/disk/` directory and related symlinks. I already have udev and systemd in the system.

```
$ udevadm --version
244

$ systemctl --version
systemd 244 (244)

$ busybox --help     
BusyBox v1.31.1 () multi-call binary.
```

poky version is dunfell

The build also has `60-persistent-storage.rules` in `/lib/udev/rules.d/` along with a lot of other rules.

I wanted the `/dev/disk/by-uuid` directory so that I can implement automatic decryption of a luks partion using UUID of the partition. I have not edited any udev rules and it is in the default state.

Does anyone know why I don't have /dev/disk directory? What can I do to generate that directory and related symlinks in my embedded linux system?

Comment: What kind of disks are we talking about? I'm not used to `udev` generating anything but the `/dev/mmcblkX` stuff, but maybe I just don't know your system.

Comment: @Philippos The disk is an SD-card with multiple partitions including a root partition. I flashed the image into it to create a bootable SD-card. From my research on the internet udev is responsible for creating /dev/disk/ and associated symlinks.

Comment: But do you have the partitions accessible as `/dev/mmcblkXpY`?

Comment: @Philippos Yes. all partitions are showing up as /dev/mmcblkXpY. I was able to list them with lsblk.

Comment: Okay, and how did you configure `udev` to have your partitions show in `/dev/disks`? (I'm sorry have to ask stupid questions because I never did this)

Comment: @Philippos I didn't do any udev configuration. Desktop linux distributions create /dev/disk automatically without any configuration. So I thought this should too. From my understanding '/lib/udev/rules.d/60-persistent-storage.rules' has the necessary stuff for this.